# Passing an NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: swift, core-data

I've been experimenting with how to pass my managed object context throughout my application in Core Data and I came across an approach that I'd like reviewed.

I've been creating a protocol for all of my View Controllers that need a managed object context to implement:

```
protocol ManagedObjectContextProperty {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext! { get set }
}
```

Then I create an extension to that protocol to assert that the context does indeed exist:

```
extension ManagedObjectContextProperty {
    func checkManagedObjectContext(name: String) {
        if managedObjectContext == nil {
            assertionFailure("\(name) is missing the managed object context.")
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I create an extension that fetches my context from the app delegate and add's it to my `managedObjectContext` variable:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func getManagedObjectContext<T : UIViewController where T : ManagedObjectContextProperty>(controller: T) {
        var controller = controller
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
        controller.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    }
}
```

Then in my View Controller I simply do this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ManagedObjectContextProperty {

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        getManagedObjectContext(controller: self)
        checkManagedObjectContext(name: "ViewController")
    }
}
```

Is this approach is against the general convention? If so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found an answer that I can appreciate. From Marcus Zarra's blog:

> A view controller typically shouldn’t retrieve the context from a
>   global object such as the application delegate. This tends to make the
>   application architecture rigid. Neither should a view controller
>   typically create a context for its own use. This may mean that
>   operations performed using the controller’s context aren’t registered
>   with other contexts, so different view controllers will have different
>   perspectives on the data.

source: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/01/07/passing-around-a-nsmanagedobjectcontext-on-the-iphone/

Look's like I'll go back to passing the managed object context via Segue.